# Caching, how do you deal with stale data

Tags: caching, hazelcast

So I am looking at caching using hazelcast and spring, what i found is caching works if im pulling data out say by Id and then updating a single record.

However what if i want to read a set of rows, say

```
select * from Orders where orderDate='2021-05-26'
```

This returns me a set of orders, if i store this in the cache great any query for those rows will bring those rows back quickly for various instances (if i configure them all). However if i update the rows:

```
Update orders set delivered='true' where orderDate='2021-05-26'
```

How will the cache get updated, and if more orders are added on that day, how does the cache work?

IT makes sense for one record using an id, a cache miss go to DB. But would additional rows being missed mean its a cache miss?

Answer (score 0):

So the L2 Cache aka Read-Through Cache is implemented using a [Map Store](https://docs.hazelcast.com/cloud/maploader-and-mapstore.html) API which includes a Map Loader API that will load the requested data by key.  If you are not requesting by key then it will not goto the map store to fetch the data instead you have a few choices:

1. during startup your map loader load all will attempt to load all the data from your store into Hazelcast (I'm not a fan of this since you most likely want to refresh the cache ad hoc or on demand).
2. use [Jet](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet) or an [IMDG](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast) client (be sure to use [pipelining](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/performance/pipelining.html)) to refresh the cache on demand. This gives you total control over when the data is loaded.
3. use [Jet with CDC](https://jet-start.sh/docs/tutorials/cdc) (Change Data Capture) which involves reading the tlog from your database and having Hazelcast push the changes in an Event Driven Architecture.